# overriding plugin styles dynamik genesis

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I have a site that is using the Genesis Framework and the Dynamik child theme from cobalt apps. I'm running into a problem with overriding plugin styles. Unlike a normal genesis child theme, all custom styles must be done in the theme options page in the WordPress Admin, and any custom styles I have tried to make will not override. What is the best way to work around this?

Comment: This might be of some use http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101037/how-do-i-cleanly-override-a-plugins-css-with-a-child-theme

Comment: You could change the default values of the custom css in the options page to match what you would add yourself in a stylesheet - or alternatively (while this isn't the best way to get the result) you could use `!important` in your style rules.

Comment: Also since styles are set in the theme options page I assume they are printed out directly to a `<style>...</style>` block in the page?

Comment: I've tried adding `!important` to everything, I've tried adding add an external stylesheet, and I've tried injecting inline styles and nothing has worked.

Comment: Can you share your link if possible, with the exact element you are trying to override styles for? So we can see what and how Dynamik is overriding your styles and how we can specify css to override that.